# how to add documentation to a Svelte Component on hover inside VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, documentation, sveltekit

I'm working on a Svelte project in VSCode, and I'd like to provide some additional documentation for my Svelte components. Specifically, I want to add some simple lines of text that appear in a popup when the user hovers over the component.

Currently, when I hover over a Svelte component in VSCode, I see the following default text:

> (alias) class MyComponent
> import MyComponent

However, I want to add some custom text that explains how to use the component properly. (For example, for some components to work correctly, I need to tell the user to apply a tailwind class `peer` to the previous element.)

Is there a way to add this type of documentation to Svelte components in VSCode? Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify the documentation text in a comment within the component file itself.

It would also be great if the documentation text could support markdown formatting, including headers (#, ##, ###), links, ---- dividers, - lists and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can using vscode:

basically you need to create a html `<!-- -->` comment at the start of your `*.svelte` file which includes at the beggining `@component`

---

## Example:

example using your example issue:

```html
<!--
  @component
  ## To make this work:
  You MUST SET `peer` tailwind class, to the previous HTML element manually

  ### Notes:
  you may need to style your parent element by adding `flex flex-row-reverse`, add some `gap` and so on... because this component is just a tooltip, not a container
-->
```

as you see you can use also Markdown inside the comment.

---

## how it looks?

on hover of the `import`:
[image]

on hover of the component itself:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same issue as in this question.

This question has useful answers: [Is there a standard way to document Svelte components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125395/is-there-a-standard-way-to-document-svelte-components)

To summarize from that question:

- Svelte does provide broad guidelines to document components [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/HEAD/docs/README.md#documenting-components) and in [their FAQ](https://svelte.dev/faq#how-do-i-document-my-components). I am using this way and can see the documentation reflected on hover in VS Code. It does not work on Webstorm though. But since you mentioned VS Code, I think this should be adequate for your need.
- There are other packages like [sveld](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sveld/v/0.14.0), [sveltedoc-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sveltedoc-parser) but I haven't been able to get them working for Svelte3. My work projects are based on Svelte3.

This question should probably be marked as a duplicate.